# Unable to mint tokens using a PDA

Tags: anchor, solana-program, anchor-lang

I'm trying to make a program that's able to get mint authorization on a PDA (first function), and then mint tokens using that authorization. My transfer authorization function works fine (tested on devnet), but I can't get the mint to work. I keep getting "Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account." error.

On most of the exemples for a minting function, the mint (the token) is created by the program. Here that's not the case. I guess I'm doing something wrong there?

Also, I'm forced to clone another_authority so I don't do a mutable and immutable borrow in the same scope. Is it wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your seeds in the second method is different from the first, you forgot to add the `b"autho"` prefix. Make the following change and your code is good to go:

```
 let seeds: &[&[u8]] = &[
     b"autho",                          // Seed 0: autho PREFIX
     another_authority.admin.as_ref(),  // Seed 1: Admin's public key
     bump_seed,                         // Seed 2: Bump nonce
 ];

 let signer_seeds = &[&seeds[..]];
```

Comment: Indeed, it now works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great! If it worked, you can accept the answer to close the question.

Answer (score 2):

Just at quick glance, it looks like you are not passing in all your seeds in your minting function. Specifically, I think you need to add `b"autho"` into your `seeds` declaration.

Here's an example similar to yours:
https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/blob/d6cd69d8df3eb95966b3d2361ede84529413567a/tokens/pda-mint-authority/anchor/programs/token-minter/src/instructions/mint.rs#L46

FYI you can also use the `seeds` constraint in your `Minting` struct to help ensure you're passing a valid PDA (it's not limited to use only with `init`).

Comment: Indeed, it now works. Thanks a lot!